# How to make Tetris blocks fall down every second (error)

Tags: java, swing

Beginner Java developer. Trying to make a Tetris applet as part of my personal projects.

I'm at the point were I can draw tetris blocks onto the screen but I cannot make it vertically go downwards every second.

Code:

```
 public class InitialScreen extends JApplet implements ActionListener {
 public JPanel cards = new JPanel();
 private JPanel introPanel = new JPanel();
 public CardLayout c1 = new CardLayout();

public void init() {
    initiateIntroScreen();
    //game();
    add(cards, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    setSize(500, 100);
}



private void initiateIntroScreen() {
    Frame title = (Frame)this.getParent().getParent();


    cards.setLayout(c1);

    JLabel centralWords = new JLabel("Click the following button options: 'Play' or 'Instructions'.");
    JButton playBtn = new JButton("Play!");
    JButton instructionsBtn = new JButton("Instructions!");

    introPanel.add(centralWords);
    introPanel.add(playBtn);
    introPanel.add(instructionsBtn);
    cards.add(introPanel,"1");

    playBtn.addActionListener(this);
    playBtn.addActionListener(new MainGame(cards,c1));


}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    setSize(300,410);
    getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
}
```

So this is the initial screen for the JApplet. Has two buttons. When you press the 'Play' button it goes to the Main Game Screen.

```
public class MainGame extends JApplet implements ActionListener {
private JPanel cards;
private CardLayout c1;
private JPanel gamePanel = new JPanel();

public MainGame(JPanel cards, CardLayout c1) {
    this.c1 = c1;
    this.cards = cards;
    gamePanel.add(new Tetris_Block(new int[10][20]));
}


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JLabel scoreLbl = new JLabel("Score:");
    gamePanel.add(scoreLbl);
    cards.add(gamePanel,"game");
    c1.show(cards,"game");

}
```

This is the game screen were Tetris is played. In the constructor it calls a Tetris Block.

```
public class Tetris_Block extends JComponent implements ActionListener {
static Color[] colors =
        {darkGray, green, blue, red,
                yellow, magenta, pink, cyan};
int[][] a;
int w, h;
static int horizontalPos, verticalPos = 0;
static int size = 20;
private int verticalPos1 = 1;

public Tetris_Block(int[][] a) {
    this.a = a;
    w = a.length;
    h = a[0].length;
    square_Block();
    startTimer();
}

private void nextMove() {
    verticalPos++;
    verticalPos1++;
}

 public void square_Block(){ //Horizontal || Vertical || Colour

    //Horizontal never changes for this as I just want the blocks to go down.
    a[0][verticalPos] = 3;
    a[0][verticalPos1] = 3;
    a[1][verticalPos] = 3;
    a[1][verticalPos1] = 3;
}


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    nextMove();
    square_Block();
    System.out.println(verticalPos);
}


public void startTimer(){
    Timer timer = new Timer(1000,this);
    timer.start();
}


public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    for (int i = 0; i < w; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < h; j++) {
                g.setColor(colors[a[i][j]]);
                g.fill3DRect(i * size, j * size,
                        size, size, true);

            }
        }
    }


public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(w * size, h * size);
}
```

**My aim is to make the vertical position increment by 1 every second (So it goes down the window in second intervals.**

I don't think the Timer function is the problem. When I print verticalPos it prints out the incremented value every second, however it's just displaying the new location onto the screen- that is the problem.

Image of window right now.

[img]https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHQVA.png

Comment: Too much code to help. Please narrow your question down and ask a specific question

Comment: @SethKitchen It's literally the Tetris_Block class that needs to be looked at. I added the others just for context.

Comment: I recommend deleting everything. Post 1 or 2 functions that don't work and tell us why not and what you want them to do

Comment: @azurefrog Yeah I am using java.util.Timer (Swing Timer) However I don't think the Timer is the fault. When I run the code it successfully prints out the incremented verticalPos every second. It's just pasting the new location onto the screena again.

Comment: Yeah, I found the swing Timer after a bit.  I see you are updating some positions in your `actionPerformed` method, but I don't see anywhere that you redraw the screen afterwards.

Comment: Now I think that is the problem. I call square_Block method again thinking that the blocks will redraw onto the screen with the new positions. Is that the wrong way to do it?

Comment: All that square_Block is doing is updating ints in an array.  If you want to change what is displayed on the screen based on the updated data, you need to repaint.

Comment: @azurefrog That is calling paintComponent method again?

Comment: Take a look at [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html), notice that after the data changes, they call `animator.repaint();`

Comment: Save your self some headaches and ditch `JApplet`,  start by making all your views extend from something like `JPanel` and use a `CardLayout` to switch between them.  Use a instance of a `JFrame` as a basic testing ground, this will reduce the number of issues you need to solve as you get started

Comment: @MadProgrammer For this I have to use JApplet. Can't use anything else.

Comment: @azurefrog So is calling the repaint method supposed to solve the issue?

Comment: I'm not swing expert, so I don't know what in particular you'll need to repaint, just that currently you aren't repainting anything.

Comment: @bob9123 Then tell you instructor they are in idiot and are out of touch of the real world.  Most web browser actively disable the applet plugin and there are a lot of better was to achieve the same result.  Okay, so start by making all you views `JPanel`s.  Use a single `JApplet` to manage them, just like you would have done with a `JFrame`

Comment: @bob9123 You're also breaking the contract of the paint chain by not calling `super.paintComponent` in your `paintComponent` method of your `Tetris_Block` class

Comment: Do I need to use JFrame at all to get this done? I firstly used JFrames embedded JApplet but I did not want to risk it.

Comment: To solve the issue, do I not have to make sure paintComponent is called every second?

Comment: @bob9123 You shouldn't be embedding `JFrame` in `JAppets` any way, the security manager will prevent you from making windows.  Just use the `JApplet` as the top level container, all other logic should be separated in your other classes/view, which should extend from `JPanel`, this way, you can change the top level container when ever you want to

Comment: @bob9123 FYI `Frame title = (Frame)this.getParent().getParent();` is a bad idea. This will work only while you're using a applet viewer

Comment: Yeah, it will be getting looked at using applet viewer. For future purposes, what is the best way to do? I used this to get control with the setTitle method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start by adding a call to `repaint` in you `actionPerformed` method of your `Tetris_Block`

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    nextMove();
    square_Block();
    System.out.println(verticalPos);
    // This is important
    repaint();
}
```

This will schedule a paint event on the event queue which will eventually call your `paintComponent` method (indirectly)

This will get the block to start moving.  The next problem you will have is you're not actually "removing" the block from it's previous position, so it will continue to bleed/grow down the screen

[image: Bleeding blocks]

You could solve this by passing in the color of the block to `square_Block`, for example...

```
public void square_Block(int color) { //Horizontal || Vertical || Colour

    //Horizontal never changes for this as I just want the blocks to go down.
    a[0][verticalPos] = color;
    a[0][verticalPos1] = color;
    a[1][verticalPos] = color;
    a[1][verticalPos1] = color;
}
```

And then "rest" the blocks of the current position, update the position and then set the new block colors;

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    square_Block(0);
    nextMove();
    square_Block(3);
    System.out.println(verticalPos);
    repaint();
}
```

[image: Falling]

Comment: Thanks very much. For some reason I did try repaint method however it did not work. Not sure what changed.

Answer (score 0):

Your design here may be faulty. You need to have a game loop that runs in a separate thread. It has to be a separate thread from the main thread so the user can still click buttons. Once you have a loop in the separate thread you need to have a method that you call for every game tick. It's in that method that you update the coordinates of the blocks.

Game loop works like this:
1. Read state of the game and draw the blocks
2. Process user input.
3. Update game state

I know this is abstract but I hope it helps. Google about java games and game loops.

Comment: He's already using a Swing Timer which does all waiting in a background thread (behind the scenes), and so there's no need to use a background thread explicitly as you've suggested.

Comment: If a falling block is as far as he wants to go then I agree. However, it's going to be hard to implement new features like pausing, and managing user input if he doesn't design it right in the first place.

Comment: Block collisions will also be difficult when a proper game loop is not implemented.

Comment: But that's what I'm getting at -- using a Swing Timer will allow for all of this if done correctly. It can be used as a full fledged game loop.

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying. You are just saying let the timer control the game loop instead of creating and managing a separate thread manually. I agree.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I will have to have user input (down arrow key to make drop faster) and also game collisions (blocks have to stack on top of each other). However I've seen examples were there were no threads etc. So I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes, exactly. The problem with the Timer is that like most all timers, the time split is not fully accurate, and so all physics should be based on actual measured delta time.

Comment: I have no idea about the thread topic. I will have to research heavily as it will help me out.

Comment: I don't see where your paintComponent method is taking into account the vertical position. So your position is probably changing with your timer correctly, but your paintComponent method is not honoring it.

Comment: @JoshChappelle Yeah I the issue is solved. I just had to repaint the blocks onto the screen after changing the position.